# UnsatisfiedLinkError for JNI function from Xtext project

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, xtext

I have a Xtext project and for the validator, I need to call C++ functions. I have generated the header file and created the corresponding cpp file
DummyValidator.h

```cpp
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator
#define _Included_com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

DummyValidator.cpp

```cpp
#include "DummyValidator.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL

Java_com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator_print(JNIEnv *, jobject){

    cout << "Oh Bob, how handsome you are!\n";

    return;

}
```

In the project properties, I have added the library path to `Java Build Path`

```
Native library loc: dummy_validator/Debug
```

But once I run the xtext project as an Eclipse application, while working on the DSL, I get the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.example.validation.DummyValidator.print()'
```

The validator code looks like:

```java
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.25.0
 */
package com.example.dummy.validation;

import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Check;

import dummy.DummyType;

/**
 * This class contains custom validation rules. 
 *
 * See https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#validation
 */
public class DummyValidator extends AbstractDummyValidator {
    
    private native void print();
    
    public static final String INVALID_NAME = "invalidName";

        
    @Check
    public void checkUniqueNames(DummyType dummy) {
        print();    // UnsatisfiedLinkError
    }
    
    static {

        System.loadLibrary("dummy_validator");

    } 
}
```

Looks like the library is getting loaded properly. Also, if I load the library from a standalone Java project it works fine.

```java
package com.example.dummy.validation;

class DummyValidator {

    private native void print();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("dummy_validator");
        new DummyValidator().print();    // works fine
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:** The output for

```
System.out.println("java path: " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
```

does not include the library path in case of Xtext, but it does include for the Java project, even though the settings are the same. What do I need to do differently in case of Xtext?

**Edit 2:** I added the library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the runtime configuration and now the `java.library.path` does show the correct library path, but still the same error.

**Edit 3:** I added this code in the check function to list the libraries loaded and my library is shown in the list.

```java
Field libs;
        try {
            libs = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("loadedLibraryNames");
            libs.setAccessible(true);
            Object libraries = libs.get(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
            System.out.println(libraries);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So the library is in fact getting loaded.

Comment: Oh, i think i have an idea. Are you absolutely sure that the library is being loaded? How about putting a log statement below to verify or something.

I'm thinking, is the `@Check` annotated method ran during application runtime, or before, during compilation? You will not be able to load a library at compile-time, as the `static` blocks will not have been executed.

Comment: I tried `System.loadLibrary` call inside the check function, but the same error.

Comment: Is the library even found? Put a log at the entry point of your application, does the crash happen after that log gets printed or after?

Comment: if I comment the `print()` function, there is no crash, and the crash log gets printed after the `System.out.println` at entry point.

Comment: @Shark please check `Edit 3`

Comment: And it worked!! During all the testing, I had copied an old library with wrong function name in the root of the plugin. And that was the one getting loaded. Once I deleted that, I see the log from c++!!

Comment: There you go, glad to have helped. Thats why you want to start off these things by writing a script to automate this, so you don't chase stupid "omg i forgot <insert whatever>" problems down the rabbit hole.

Comment: FWIW, from Java 15 onwards, you can use `-Xlog:library*=trace` to print out the function  names it's using for the lookup. In this case it looks like a mismatch between the Java method name, and the native function name: `Java_com_example_dummy_validation_DummyValidator_print` vs `void com.example.validation.DummyValidator.print()` (notice that the former has an extra 'dummy' in there).